# android - How to simulate button pressed by greying out an ImageView?

Tags: android, animation, button, imageview

I want to create a control panel at the bottom of my screen that looks something like this.

Here is the image

[image]

And I want to simulate button press by having the clicked on item be blacked, and everything that isn't clicked be greyed out. As shown in the image, the picture icon had been clicked on.

At the moment, my solution is to overlay two rows of identical ImageViews. One layer consist of all black icons, and one layer consist of all grey icons. When I click on an image, I run a code that looks like this:

```
private void galleryClicked() {
        mGalleryImageView_unclicked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mPersonalImageView_unclicked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mExploreImageView_unclicked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mMenuImageView_unclicked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mGalleryImageView_clicked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mPersonalImageView_clicked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mExploreImageView_clicked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mMenuImageView_clicked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

I'm just wondering if there's a more efficient or better way of doing this. When I run this on my phone, and can feel some lag in the response. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Radiobutton`s with `RadioGroup`, and each `RadioButton` has its own selector `Drawable`. Then the `RadioGroup` will take care of the selection for you (check one will uncheck all others).

Example code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/item_one"
            style="@style/TabItem"
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_tab_item_one" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/item_two"
            style="@style/TabItem"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_tab_item_two" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/item_three"
            style="@style/TabItem"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_tab_item_three" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/item_four"
            style="@style/TabItem"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_tab_item_four"/>
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Declare `@style/TabItem` in `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="TabItem" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">bottom|center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

The selector `Drawable` is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_one_highlighted" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_one_highlighted" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_one_default" />
</selector>
```

Results:

[image: preview]

Comment: Ah, I completely forgot about the radio button. Have used them before, for some reason just didn't pop into my mind. Thank you! This is probably the better and correct answer. But since I've already implemented the method by the answer above, I'll just leave it as it is now. I will mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have better solution, that is using selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/clicked" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unclicked" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

so now you just set  `mGalleryImageView.setEnabled(true);` or  `mGalleryImageView.setEnabled(false)`

Comment: Thank you! I've implemented your method, and it worked great. But I've just noticed the answer below, and that answer is probably more correct. But I'm going to keep using ur solution for now. Thank you for your answer!